# XAML C# как сохранять и загружать данные dataSet dataGrid в файл

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, datatable, typed-dataset

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в XAML C# использовать таблицу в памяти без базы данных, сохранять из таблицы DataGrid данные в файл (допустим в .txt) и загружать данные в таблицу DataGrid. Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Структура файла заранее известна?

Comment: Мне без разницы можно .txt главное оттолкнуться. Не могу понять как сохранять, везде пишут о базах данных вроде таких как SQL, а мне надо чтобы сохраняло в саму программу и данные хранились в самой программе.

Comment: обычный текстовый файл тоже может рассматриваться как база данных

Comment: я имею ввиду вы знаете заранее что хранится в файле?

Comment: не каждую конкретную строчку, а общую структуру. (Например, каждая строка файла содержит четыре значения разделенных пробелами)

Comment: Главное вообще не за что зацепиться, сколько не капал везде про базы данных пишут, пишут про то как создать таблицы, нигде не нашёл как сохранять файлы, SQL на каждом ходу в яндексе выскакивает, но самое интересное только поверхность описывают, вообщем оттолкнуться не отчего.

Comment: извините, но вы точно читаете то, что я вам пишу? Вы второй раз пишите об одном и том-же, но ваш текст никак не связан ни с одним моим комментарием.

Comment: Я сейчас попробую сформулировать, пока Вам писал предыдущую тему Вы мне уже ответили.

Comment: Заранее что храниться в файле неизвестно или я не понял вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67540/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-).